# Which program or software do I need to use to replicate more of these gifs?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

https://i.stack.imgur.com/V20dI.jpg

I'm planning on making tons of GIFs / animated images, but would like to know where to start.

Comment: Will you be creating your own assets or using stock images?
You may need a combination of Illustrator and Photoshop or Illustrator and AfterEffects if you go down the adobe route. Have you ever done animations like this before?

Comment: That is not a good plan...

Comment: If you have the Adobe suite, Adobe Animate is also a good single tool for creating GIFs.

Answer (score 5):

That is not a GIF, that is an MP4 file, but ok, that is a minor detail.

1. You need a program to draw the elements, a person, the screen, the shadow. Use a vector-based program.

   - Inkscape => Free
   - Illustrator
   - Corel Draw
   - Affinity design
   - Gravit Design
   - https://duckduckgo.com/?q=vector+based+program&atb=v147-1&ia=web
2. A program to animate the elements in a loop.

   - Blender => Free
   - NCH Animation Express => Free
   - Hit Film Express => Free
   - After effects
3. Probably a program to convert the rendered video into an animated gif.

Comment: For the 3rd point, a program isn't exactly required. There are online services like [cloudconvert](https://cloudconvert.com/), [ezgif](https://ezgif.com/video-to-gif) (didn't like that one) or [zamzar](https://www.zamzar.com/convert/mp4-to-gif/). For programs, the most common seems to be [handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/) but [FormatFactory](http://www.pcfreetime.com/formatfactory/index.php?language=en) is one I've been using for years.

Comment: If using After Effects you can export gif. Also that file on imgur being mp4 is an imgur internal engine for showing gifs. Some larger gifs are made into mp4 for size compression.

Comment: Photoshop can also do the 2nd step.

Comment: Photoshop does more like a frame by frame animation. I am too lazy for that and prefer a real animation program. :o)